# how can I make this kind of Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, design-patterns, flutter-layout

How can I make a `Container` like this?

[image]

If anybody knows how to do it then let me know.

Comment: `ClipPath`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAUebVIb-7s&ab_channel=Flutter

Comment: I tried a lot but didn't make it with Clip path which Clip path property is used to make something like that . can you please let me know about that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this flutter package --> [Flutter Custom Clipper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers)

Your required shape can be achieved..